# Google analytics for Django app only shows root domain instead of page titles

Tags: django, google-analytics

I've got my first Django app in production and would like to setup Google Analytics to see pageviews/timespent/etc by page title for the order flow. I've added the GA javascript to the  of my base.html template with the hope that it would track each page with page title.

However, when I look at Google Analytics, I only see page views by my root domain 'mysite.com', and I cannot get get page views by '/app/pagetitle1', '/app/pagetitle2', '/app/pagetitle3', etc. 'app' is the Django app that the root domain gets redirected to 'mysite.com/app'. I'm assuming that Google Analytics would show entire path after root domain, if it were to work.

[image]

It seems like there is probably something simple I've overlooked, and would appreciate any advice.

Here's the GA tag I put in base.html right after  per GA instructions:

```
      <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXX"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'XXX');
        </script>
```

Each template extends base.html as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

        <section class="container container-interior">
etc - rest of <body>
```

Comment: You have the same issue as this guy here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067424/how-to-trigger-a-page-view-event-in-google-analytics-on-a-single-page-applicatio/66071072#66071072

Implement it like he did, so essentially you need to send a "pageview" when the django app routes. Set the initial code to "not track pageview".

Answer (score 0):

I made two changes to address lack of page title and double counting.

1. Remove this gtag call from my base.html template
   gtag('config', 'G-ID',{'send_page_view': true});
2. Added this to each page that I wanted to track using a block tag.
   gtag('event', 'page_view', { page_title: '', page_path: ', send_to: '<G-ID'> })